# i have to use wavefile from scipy.io but i can't

Tags: python, scipy, wav, attributeerror

```
import os
from scipy import io
in_dir='dev'
files=os.listdir(in_dir)
file_paths=[os.path.join(in_dir,f) for f in files]
io.wavfile.read(file_paths)
```

i have written this code because i want  to read some wav files.
if i run the program i get this error:

```
----> 6 io.wavfile.read(file_paths)

AttributeError: module 'scipy.io' has no attribute 'wavfile'
```

i'm sure that i've imported the module in the right way and i think the problem could be in the package that i've installed. Do you have any suggestions?
if the problem is the installation of the scipy how can i reinstall it correctly?

Comment: Should be `wavfile` not `wavefile` for the WAV file format

Comment: i tried now but i get exactly the same error

Comment: no ,that's not the same question

Comment: I tried your code, I had the same error. I tried the code in the linked answer, it worked successfully. I think that fixes it

Comment: yes ok, i just tried and now it works. thank you